# Can removal of a cubic millimetre of tissue lead to a person's death?

Tags: medical-science

The ComplexityBlog makes this [claim](http://complexityblog.com/blog/index.php?itemid=82)

> For the robust/vulnerable dichotomy we can take the human body as clear example of a complex system. It is extremely robust to certain insults, like the removal of a limb or a lung, which are large and disruptive, but can be dealt with. On the other hand, **there are some specific regions in the brain and heart where the removal of just a cubic millimeter of tissue results in the immediate death of the individual**.

(emphasis mine)

Is this correct?

Comment: How exactly is one going to remove that one cubic millimeter?

Comment: How thick is the nerve fibre going to the diaphragm? Severing that one might have pretty severe consequences.

Comment: Disconnecting the heart from the brain might be pretty bad, too.

Comment: Seems a silly thing to say. I guess magic teleportation can be lethal. Perhaps this question should be on the scifi or world-building stack Exchange.

Comment: @JanDvorak Concentrated radiotherapy beams or microwaves converging on one spot from different directions could burn an area as small as a cubic millimetre without significant damage to surrounding tissue. I don't know of any specific medical systems that are this precise yet, but systems like ["cyberknife"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyberknife) are pretty close (5mm), so it's just a matter of time if it doesn't already exist. And anyway, the point of the question is, "Are there tissues as small as 1mm that are completely essential for human life" not "Can someone do this today"

Comment: This sounds like a good fit for biology.se, but just from a recent first aid refresher course I recall that your entire heart rhythm is directed by a very tiny knot of neural tissue (which is what we try to reset when we use a defibrillator). If that were to suddenly go missing, you'd wind up dead in short order.

Comment: @JanDvorak More or less 1.44x0.51mm, from https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/25050670. Could cut a >1mm section of it. But there are two, so a 1mm^3 wouldn't be enough...

Comment: @Shadur from what I remember, there are two backups. If the primary generator goes haywire, the backups can't override it, but if the primary goes missing, these should kick in. Though, if I remember correctly, these tick at a lower rate than the primary, so that might not be quite enough for survival. Good call.

Comment: @woliveirajr what if I remove half a cubic millimeter from both? I suppose it's against the rules of this challenge, but would it kill the person?

Comment: @fredsbend if magic teleportation is allowed, I suggest carrying a bottle of hydrogen cyanide and teleporting drops of it into the person. Requires less precision and knowledge of human anatomy.

Comment: The spinal cord is [8 to 11 mm thick](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=Gi6wjdftC7cC&lpg=PA38&ots=tcoxENCkuC&dq=thickness%20of%20the%20spinal%20cord&hl=pt-BR&pg=PA38#v=onepage&q&f=false) - if you cut the red nerve (and not the blue one) maybe you can kill a person, good luck finding a reliable scientific source to that.

Comment: @JanDvorak well, we might consider that cutting a nerve isn't removing material from it, as a scalpel has a width of 0.22mm (not the edge!). So, the removal would be on the cells that are cutted in half, i.e., the lost material would be cells that aren't integer anymore... with that criteria, 1mm3 is a lot of thing.

Comment: @woliveirajr I like that line of thinking. How thin of a blade do you need to cut the entire spinal cord off? Perhaps slicing the heart in half would be too easy... Maybe we should focus on actual 1mm*1mm*1mm cubes...

Comment: @JanDvorak I think the problem will we with the "immediate". You can remove 1mm3 from a cerebral artery and cause a hemorrhagic condition, that can lead to death, but it will take some time.

Comment: @woliveirajr then the answer is a definite no. Even if you remove the entire heart, they still have a decent amount of time to go before they lose consciousness. Enough to stab the mage (if he's in melee range) or dial the emergency number. Maybe both.

Comment: It's worth noting that 'cubic millimeter' could refer to 1mm*1mm*1mm... but it could also refer to  5mm*5mm*0.04mm etc.

Comment: Useful reading: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardiac_pacemaker; the SA node takes inputs from the brain to regulate the frequency. Failing brain input, it runs at 100 BPM (a bit fast, but nothing extraordinary; probably not great in the long-term). If the SA node fails, the AV node kicks in at 40-60 BPM - not very fast, but it should keep the person alive and conscious. The second backup runs at 30-40 BPM, which is rather slow, but I feel like it might be enough to keep one unconscious brain alive.

Comment: Good points, since severing those connections doesn't even require removal of tissue.

Answer (score 5):

I am a physician and i know certain areas in the body that can lead to death. Certain areas in the *medulla oblongata* such as the respiratory centre and the conduction pathway bundles in the heart qualify as such points where damage to or removal of a cubic mm may have devastating consequences. Imminent death is certainly a possibility.

In the comments, it has been suggested that cutting the nerve to the diaphragm may cause death, which is not true. A diaphragmatic palsy is quite common and even in a bilateral palsy where both sides are paralyzed, [this is only associated with a reduction in lung capacity](https://www.cedars-sinai.edu/Patients/Health-Conditions/Paralyzed-Diaphragm.aspx). As regards the comments about how one might make such a removal, a 1 cu mm lesion can be produced by techniques such as [radiofrequency ablation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiofrequency_ablation) where a needle is passed to the target and tissue is destroyed using currents.

Comment: [Welcome to Skeptics!](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/welcome-to-new-users) We have no way of knowing whether you have the appropriate expertise and whether what your saying is true, so we require references. Please edit it to add references to empirical data in your first paragraoh and flag it for moderator attention in order to get it reinstated. (The second paragraph is really just a response to other comments, and does not answer the question.)